In the shader editor, if I have a linear gradient, is it possible to derive a gradient that is tangential to the original?
I have some images to help clarify my question, as I'm not sure if I worded it correctly.
In the shader editor, you can achieve a gradient similar to the following by setting the gradient texture node to 'spherical':

There's also a 'radial' mode, which results in the following:

I can see a relationship between the two - it's like the second one is going 'around' the first. And by combining the two as x and y component of a UV texture, I can create an image that goes around in a circle, similar to the following:

My hope is that, instead of relying on the gradient texture node, it's possible to derive the second gradient from the first.
The reason is that I'd like to be able to take any gradient as an input (say for example a noise texture, or gradient generated in external image editing software), and from that derive another gradient that is the 'radial' version of the original.
An example use case is what I mentioned above - plugging each of the gradients into the x and y components of a UV texture.

The problem with the above technique is that it's limited to a circular shape whereas, as I say, I'd like to be able to use custom gradients of any shape.

Any pointers into the math behind this, or whether it's possible at all would be much appreciated!

You probably can derive one gradient from the other if you sample it at multiple points and compare the change to what you would expect for an undeformed gradient...

Thanks Markus, that’s an interesting idea. Does the term sampling imply that geometry nodes would be required? Or would the process you describe be possible from within the shader editor?
